# show date limited in select tag Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, date, time

I need to display date limited in SELECT tag HTML by loop php and wordpress  . 
only need to display four days later.

like sample image :

[image]

Also, for hours and minutes this way.

thanks .

Comment: Hello Mehdi, first of all, welcome to SO ! Please don't forget this site is not a coding service... If you encouter a problem or have a specific question, you are invited to ask it in a concise and explicit maneer. This way you will get a better help, and other people will be able to find answer more easilly if they encounter the same problem as you. Please refer to the documentation on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

get today

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

you can loop over this to get the next days

```
$next_dates = date('DD', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
```

loop example

```
 for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $next_date = date('DD', strtotime($date .' +1 day'));
    echo "The next is: $next_date <br>";
}
```

you can put your data then in `<select>` tag as `<option>`